# Dialog on top of everything

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-layout

Is it possible to create a Dialog in Flutter that stays on top, even if `Navigator.of(context).push()` is called?

Comment: It is possible, but how you do it will depend on your application's code. You could achieve this with a top-level Stack widget and a second navigator.

Comment: I am currently just planing my new application. So every solution should work for me.
With top-level Stack widget you mean a Stack as a root Widget that holds the MaterialApp as a child?

Comment: @AlexMeuer
Thanks, you brought me on the right track.